# Flutter video_player Playing Multiple Videos Causing Out Of Memory Error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, video-player

I am trying to build an app like instagram i'll share the screenshot for the cause of error. But every time i'm trying to play more than 3 or 4 videos at the same time it gives memory leak. Here is the simplified code.

```
class FluUIModel {
  String? docID;
  FluModel? flu;
  UserModel? user;
  VideoPlayerController? controller;
  

  FluUIModel({
    this.flu,
    this.user,
    this.docID,
    this.controller
  });


}
```

This is the model im keeping my controller.

```
 VideoPlayerController? cont;
        if (fluM.images!.first.isVideo!) {
          cont = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
              Uri.parse(URIS.googleStorageBucket +
                  Uri.encodeComponent(fluM.images!.first.contentUrl!) +
                  URIS.mediaQuery),
              videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
                mixWithOthers: true,
              ));
        }
        FluUIModel fluUIM = FluUIModel(
            flu: fluM, user: user, docID: flu['docID'], controller: cont);
```

This is where i'm assigning it.

```
VisibilityDetector(
                                              key: Key(index.toString()),
                                              onVisibilityChanged: (info) {
                                                if (info.visibleFraction <
                                                    0.5) {
                                                  if (state.flus![index].flu!
                                                      .images!.first.isVideo!) {
                                                    state.flus![index]
                                                        .controller!
                                                        .pause();
                                                  }
                                                } else {
                                                  if (state.flus![index].flu!
                                                      .images!.first.isVideo!) {
                                                    state.flus![index]
                                                        .controller!
                                                        .play();
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: VideoPlayerController(controller))
```

[image]

And this is the view that i have strugle with.(Imagine all of these images as videos.)